# vim: how to pipe command like this?

Tags: vim

I have a text file..

```
value #value2
 value2 #value3
...
```

I want to sort -f and add two tabs before #
so I did

```
:'<,'>norm f#i^I^I |!sort -f
```

But give me a bad output!
I know a workaround,use two separated commands

```
:'<,'>norm f#i^I^I^I
:'<,'>!sort -f
```

But question is: is possible to pipe those commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `:help :normal` you'll find

> This command cannot be followed by another command, since any '|' is
>   considered part of the command.

Also note that `|` isn't a pipe. It's just a way to "concatenate" commands. Kind of like separating two shell commands with `;`. For this reason the range applied to one command does not carry over to subsequent commands.

Closest alternative I can think of not involving a custom function or some such is to use `:substitute` and re-specify the range:

```
:'<,'>s/#/\t\t\t#/ | '<,'> !sort -f
```